# Sum active record with expression rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have this code in my sql view:

```
SELECT
    reports.`date`
    reports.book_title
    SUM( reports.net_sold_count * reports.avg_list_price / 10 ) AS revenue
FROM
    reports
GROUP BY
    reports.date,
    reports.book_title
```

I need to translate it to ruby code

I have active record model

```
class Report  < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Right now I have this code:

```
Report.group(:date, :book_title)
```

But I don't know where to go next because `.sum` in all examples accepts only one argument.(http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-sum)

UPD: 
Right now, I am thinking of trying something like

```
Report.select('date, book_title, SUM( reports.net_sold_count * reports.avg_list_price / 10 ) AS revenue').group(:date, :book_title)
```

Comment: May be arel can help with it

Answer (score 1):

The `#sum` documentation is misleading. Yes, `#sum` only accepts one argument but that argument doesn't have to be a symbol corresponding to a column name, that argument can also be an SQL expression that uses the available columns. In particular, the argument to `#sum` could be the Ruby string:

```
'reports.net_sold_count * reports.avg_list_price / 10'
```

and so you could say:

```
Report.group(:date, :book_title).sum('reports.net_sold_count * reports.avg_list_price / 10')
```

That will give you a Hash that looks like:

```
{
  [some_date, some_title] => some_sum,
  ...
}
```

that you can pull apart as needed back in Ruby land.

Comment: what if I need in result  something like array of objects `[ {:date => some_date, title:=>some_title, :sum => some_sum}, .....]`  (like results that will be from executing sql code, i pprovided)

Comment: Then you would "pull [it] apart as needed" with a trivial bit of Ruby, probably using something like `map { |(a,b),c| { :a => a, :b => b, :c => c } }`.